# Correlating categorical variables.

Tags: multicollinearity, cross-correlation, statsmodels, pandas

I have a collection of dummy variables.

Each record has an entry in each category

- Income: Low, Low-Mid, High-Mid, High.
- Education: Low, Low-Mid, High-Mid, High.
- Occupation: Unemployed, Manual Laborer, Professional, Executive.

The first few lines of the pandas dataframe look something like:

```
    educ_low    educ_low_mid    educ_high_mid   educ_high   inc_low inc_low_mid inc_high_mid    inc_high    professional    manual_worker   white_collar    executive
    103981  0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
    103984  0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
    103985  1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I suspect that there is a correlation between the three categories, low income suggests low education, suggests unemployed or manual labourer.

My current thinking is that I'd be better off with variables ranked 1-4 and then use a Pearson's Correlation, but I'm not sure.

What's the best way to check a correlation between these variables, preferably in pandas/statsmodels/etc.

The background is that they've been used in an OLS regression as separate terms and I suspect that this they are contributing to high multicollinearity in the model.

Thanks for anything you've got. Happy to provide more info if it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Income* and *Education*, at least, are ordinal variables, and it is best to treat them like ordinal variables.  For what you need to do, the easiest thing is to code them as numeric variables:  as you say, with levels of 1, 2, 3, 4; and use Spearman or Kendall correlation between the ordinal variables. This provides you with both a *p*-value for the test and a measure of the strength of association (*rho* or *tau*).

The only difficult thing will be dealing with *Occupation*.  One approach us to treat it as an ordinal variable and go from there.

However, if you treat it as a nominal variable, you will need to find the association between a nominal variable and an ordinal variable.  Probably the best test for this is an extended Cochran-Armitage test that allows for more than two levels of the categorical variable. But if that's not available, you can probably get away with using Kruskal-Wallis for a test.  Measures of association are *epsilon squared* and Freeman's *theta*.

Comment: Sal, Thanks that's really useful. I think I'll concentrate on measuring Income vs. Education and see if that's enough to make my broader point. 
My statistical chops are a bit light, to it'll take me a while to read up on some of the techniques you mention, but that's a really great place to start.